# Upgrade fails because of blcr-dkms

Tags: upgrade

When I try to update my Ubuntu 10.04 installation to 10.10 I get the following error.

```
Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade:
Trying to install blacklisted version 'blcr-dkms_0.8.2-13'

 This can be caused by:
 * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

If none of this applies, then please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the files in /var/log/dist-upgrade/ in the bug report.
```

None of the three applies to me (I think).

Now I found that this also affects someone else: https://bugs.launchpad.net/update-manager/+bug/657662

Is there here someone who knows what could be wrong? Or a workaround so that I can install Maverick Meerkat?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [the good suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5615/upgrade-to-10-10-fails-because-of-blcr-dkms/5631#5631) by [PocketSam](https://askubuntu.com/users/2179/pocketsam)

Look with `aptitude why blcr-dkms` why the package is installed, and remove that package if possible. For me, this was the package `r-cran-rmpi` which I actually don't use but installed with a `apt-get install r-cran-*` command.

Don't forget to do a `apt-get autoremove` to really uninstall the blcr-dkms package automatically.

The reason for this package not working is explained [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/blcr/+bug/555729)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you may try to remove this module using dkms?

```
sudo dkms uninstall blcr-dkms 
sudo dkms remove -all blcr-dkms
```

Have no idea if it will break something.
 BLCR (Berkeley Lab Checkpoint/Restart) allows programs running on Linux to be "checkpointed" (written entirely to a file), and then later "restarted".

Answer (score 2):

I got the same message but when I tried for the third time using sudo update-manager -d
It worked...

Comment: Third time it worked for me too!!

Comment: As @Toby Lunn, @Bert, @pramod, it worked for me after having tried a few times.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this bug, but it seems to be solved after I did a

```
sudo apt-get install blcr-dkms
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) and simply uninstall the `blcr-dkms` package.